# Resource/book that explains in depth, sample rates for mobile or other video games

Tags: sfx, games

Looking for a book to explain technical things for games.  Or a resource.  Got some audio files that were 22500 and they are voices.  I know that I could figure it out if I thought for long enough but it would be easier if I could read it.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to do some searching to find an appropriate article or two, but you should check out [Game Audio Relevance](http://gameaudiorelevance.iasig.org/)

Comment: fyi that link looks dead from where i browse..

Comment: @georgi.m - seems to be working fine for me. it's just a link to the site, not a specific article.